# HTML5 Snake Game - add multiple food

Tags: javascript

I have followed [this guide](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/30/html5-canvas-snake-game) to make my snake game.

But now I want to add more then one food into the map.

Well, I tried putting rows with `makeFoodItem();` instead of just the default 1 row.
So like:

```
makeFoodItem();
makeFoodItem();
makeFoodItem();
makeFoodItem();
makeFoodItem();
```

Which also made 5 foods. But the score wasn't added when the snake got them, and they was just removed, and didn't added a new one when it was taken.

So I went into looking at the Function `makeFoodItem()`, which looks like this:

```
function makeFoodItem(){
  suggestedPoint = [Math.floor(Math.random()*(canvas.width/gridSize))*gridSize, Math.floor(Math.random()*(canvas.height/gridSize))*gridSize];
  if (snakeBody.some(hasPoint)) {
    makeFoodItem();
  } else {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(10,100,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(suggestedPoint[0], suggestedPoint[1], gridSize, gridSize);
  };
}
```

but I could not really figure out what to do there.

Comment: I suppose that adding a point happened, when collect it, not when put it to the grid. Your `makeFoodItem` just put the rectangle, not do anything.

Comment: you need to look for the collection function rather than the creation function.  As you said it creates the food just fine but doesn't increase the score.  The score won't be increased in the creation of food, more than likley it will be increased in a specific scoring function or collection function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function spawnMultipleFood () {
    for (let i = 0; i < spawnMoreFoodX.length; i++) {
        let spawnMultipleX = spawnMoreFoodX[i]
    for (let j = 0; j < spawnMoreFoodY.length; j++) {
        let spawnMultipleY = spawnMoreFoodY[i]

    innerBoard.fillStyle = "purple";
    innerBoard.fillRect(spawnMultipleX * grid, spawnMultipleY * grid, gridSize, gridSize)
        }
    } 
}
```

My global vars for spawnMoreFoodX and spawnMoreFoodY are an array that I loop through and set that to another variable, then plug that var in to `fillRect()`.

Comment: you set your local variable spawnMoreFoodX and Y to both equal an array